# Postgres Server on Raspberry Pi missing values

Tags: postgresql, raspberry-pi

I created a Postgres server on master raspberry pi where I am sending data from four other raspberry pi (children) there are at least 170 queries per second from children to master.

( We have four children so there will be a total approx of 700 queries per second to master )

ps:- I have created a different database for each child

Issue:-
I am missing data It is able to process only 20 queries per second and taking only alternate seconds of data ( losing data of a sec there)

(Raspberry pi configuration:- Raspberry pi 4 with 32 bit os )

Solution I thought

adding multiple rows together (would decrase the number of queries)

Any solution or method to resolve this?

Comment: That question lacks details. We have no idea what your queries and transactions look like.

Comment: It's a simple sensors data with x y z coordinate and time stamp

Comment: As I said, that is too little information.